# UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor init based on horizontalSiceClass

Tags: swift, swiftui

I can't get to work UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor init based on horizontalSizeClass -> **it doesn't do a thing**, even though the same code with UIDevice.current.localizedModel works.

I need to use horizontalSizeClass because I have slightly different UIs for both classes.

You can preview in any iPhone in portrait. When you see pink, you got it (and then please look at iPad if it's still white :-)).

```
struct testBackground: View {
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass
    
    init() {
        if horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
            UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.pink)
        }
        
// FOLLOWING WORKS:
//      if UIDevice.current.localizedModel == "iPhone"  {
//          UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.pink)
//      }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
        }.overlay(Text("Hi, pink world!"))
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment injected *after* init, so to solve this we need to move `List` into separated view and pass environment value via view constructor arguments (in `body` it is already available)

```
struct TestBackground: View {
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass
    
    var body: some View {
        ListContainerView(horizontalSizeClass: horizontalSizeClass)
    }
}

struct ListContainerView: View {
    
    init(horizontalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass?) {
        if horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
            UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.pink)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
        }.overlay(Text("Hi, pink world!"))
    }
}
```